# Extract rows based on multiple previous rows' values in SQL Server

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table with sample data like this:

```
ID  Key   User
--  ----  -----
1   a     test
2   ab    test
3   abc   test
4   abcd  test
5   e     test1
6   ef    test1
7   efg   test1
8   efgh  test1
9   t     test1
10  ty    test1
11  tyu   test1
12  tyui  test1
```

The data consists of sequential "snapshots" of a value as it is being constructed by a user. I want to return the last row for each instance of the user building up a distinct, final `Key` value. Notice how most rows' `Key` contain the entire previous row's `Key` plus an additional letter? I only want the rows that terminate such a sequence and are the longest value possible in each chain of `Keys` that successively contain the previous `Key` value.

The above sample data should return the following:

```
ID  Key   User
--  ----  -----
4   abcd  test
8   efgh  test1
12  tyui  test1
```

How do I do this?

Comment: how does `8 | efgh | test1` will satisfy the condition ?

Comment: Do the IDs represent order of insertion? How big is the table? Are there any indexes and are you allowed to add/change them? Are there more columns (how many bytes wide is each row)?

Comment: i can edit table if need and it has Thousands of rows,

Comment: Do the IDs represent order of insertion? What version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 6):

Without answers to my questions, I had to make these assumptions:

- The `ID` column represents chronology and always increases by one with no gaps.
- SQL Server 2005 or higher

*(Update: I made a small tweak that makes this work with "interleaved" data from different users, and added some interleaved and some tricky data to my fiddle.)*

So here is my stab at a solution. [See it in a SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/78ec8/3). Of note is that it simulates the `LEAD` analytic from SQL Server 2012 without a `JOIN`.

```
WITH Info AS (
  SELECT
     Grp = Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY UserName ORDER BY ID, Which) / 2,
     *
  FROM
     dbo.UserEntry U
     CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2
     ) X (Which)
)
SELECT
   ID = Max(V.ID),
   DataKey = Max(V.DataKey),
   UserName = Max(V.UserName)
FROM
   Info I
   OUTER APPLY (SELECT I.* WHERE Which = 2) V
WHERE I.Grp > 0
GROUP BY
   I.UserName,
   I.Grp
HAVING
   Max(I.DataKey) NOT LIKE Min(I.DataKey) + '_';
```

Input:

```
INSERT dbo.UserEntry (ID, DataKey, UserName)
VALUES
(1, 'a', 'test'),
(2, 'ab', 'test'),
(3, 'e', 'test1'),
(4, 'ef', 'test1'),
(5, 'abc', 'test'),
(6, 'abcd', 'test'),
(7, 'efg', 'test1'),
(8, 'efgh', 'test1'),
(9, 't', 'test1'),
(10, 'ty', 'test1'),
(11, 'tyu', 'test1'),
(12, 'tyui', 'test1'),
(13, 't', 'test1'),
(14, 'a', 'test'),
(15, 'a', 'test'),
(16, 'ab', 'test'),
(17, 'abc', 'test'),
(18, 'abcd', 'test'),
(19, 'to', 'test1'), 
(20, 'abcde', 'test'),
(21, 'top', 'test1');
```

Output:

```
ID  DataKey  UserName
--  -------  --------
6   abcd     test
8   efgh     test1
12  tyui     test1
14  a        test
20  abcde    test
21  top      test1
```

Notes: I used different column names because using reserved words as column names is not best practice (it forces you to put square brackets around the names everywhere).

The technique I used will work with a single scan. It has no joins. A properly-constructed join-based query that utilizes appropriate indexes **may** outperform it slightly in CPU and time, but this solution will have the fewest reads for sure.

**Update**

While my query may be nice, the particular data structure in this problem lends itself to a very elegant solution I did not consider when I first answered. Thanks to Andriy for the basic idea, here is a dynamite and ultra-simple query (same fiddle as above).

```
WITH Info AS (
   SELECT
      Grp = Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY UserName ORDER BY ID) - Len(DataKey),
         *
   FROM
      dbo.UserEntry U
)
SELECT
   ID = Max(I.ID),
   DataKey = Max(I.DataKey),
   I.UserName
FROM
   Info I
GROUP BY
   I.UserName,
   I.Grp;
```

Comment: Yes, I was definitely overcomplicating it with an extra grouping criterion. Great improvement. Too bad I'm now out of votes for your answer! :)

Comment: Could be mine. I unupvoted, then immediately de-unupvoted (or is it "disunupvoted"? :). Was just fooling around, sorry.

Comment: Well, so long as you do not subsequently de-disunupvote, please. Seriously. We all recognize our civic duty to avoid dis-deunupvoting. Whatever.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach:

1. Use the initial letter as a grouping criterion for a sequence.
2. Rank the rows separately for every user, sorting them by ID, and subtract the lengths of the Key values from the rankings. Use the results as another sequence grouping criterion.
3. Rank the rows again, partitioning them this time by user and the criteria from #1 and #2, and sorting them in the descending order of ID.
4. Fetch the rows with the rankings of 1.

Here's an implementation:

```
WITH partitioned AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    SeqKey = LEFT([Key], 1),
    SeqGrp = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY UserName
      ORDER BY ID
    ) - LEN([Key])
  FROM dbo.UserEntry
),
ranked AS (
  SELECT
    ID,
    [Key],
    UserName,
    rnk = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY UserName, SeqKey, SeqGrp
      ORDER BY ID DESC
    )
  FROM partitioned
)
SELECT
  ID,
  [Key],
  UserName
FROM ranked
WHERE rnk = 1
;
```

Like with @ErikE's solution, it is assumed that the ID column defines the order of a sequence. However, the above query will still work correctly if there are gaps in ID values related to the same sequence.

You can try this query [at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/39a32/24) as well. (Note: the demo uses @ErikE's DDL.)

Comment: Dynamite! (If you saw my prior comment, please ignore it!) Nice catch on the islands.

Comment: Question: if I see a radical improvement possible to your answer, but it is based on your essential technique, am I allowed to put it in my own answer? :)

Comment: @ErikE: Sure, be my guest! A word of caution: I had to abandon my [previous idea](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/14822436/1) because of a flaw in it. So, if you were contemplating something like that, I would simply like you to consider it more carefully before posting (so as not to waste your time). I'll post details about why I didn't like it, if you need them. Other than that, I've got no reserves, please feel free to use either version in your answer!

Comment: Ok see my answer now! It was truly thanks to you for an exquisite idea.

Comment: I saw your original query and was going to give you tricky data that broke it... :)

Comment: @ErikE: Thank you for the award! I know my answer *was* helpful, but... It would have deserved the award better had I come up with the improved version myself. I wish... :)

Comment: I couldn't award it to myself and you deserved it. My gambit failed: -50.

Answer (score 1):

Well this version has an assumption that chars are only added to values (not removed):

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.UserEntry t1
WHERE 
  NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT *
      FROM dbo.UserEntry t2
      WHERE t1.username = t2.username 
      AND t2.dataKey LIKE t1.dataKey + '%'
      AND t2.ID = t1.ID + 1
   )
```

You can easily change this to work with deletion of chars in dataKey.

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1206b/2)

Here is another way to do this with `LEAD` function. This way you can make the main select simpler by extending original rows with values from following rows:

```
WITH UserEntryWithNext AS (
SELECT 
  t1.*, 
  LEAD(t1.DataKey,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS NextDataKey
FROM dbo.UserEntry t1
)
SELECT * 
FROM UserEntryWithNext 
WHERE NOT NextDataKey LIKE DataKey + '%'
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the OP hasn't said what version of SQL Server, but you are right that using `LEAD` is a good idea here. Also, please see [another update to your fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ef48f/1)--your result set should be showing a row with just `a` but is not.

Comment: @ErikE the issue with `a` is easily fixable. If sequence has to grow `_%` can be used instead of `%`

Answer (score 1):

This query should give you the correct result. I'm considering the fact that there could be some gaps between IDs (there could be some missing IDs, or more than a user could be constructing a sequence at the same time).

On the inner query I'm returning every row in the table, togheter with the previous ID `prevID` that refers to the same user. I'm then joining the result of this query with `yourtable` again:

```
SELECT
  t.ID, t.DataKey, t.UserName
FROM
  yourtable t LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT t1.ID id,
           max(t1.DataKey) DataKey,
           max(t1.UserName) UserName,
           max(t2.ID) prevID
    FROM
      yourtable t1 LEFT JOIN yourtable t2
      ON
        t1.ID>t2.ID
        AND t1.UserName = t2.UserName
    GROUP BY t1.ID
  ) t2
  ON t2.prevID = t.ID
     AND t2.UserName = t.UserName
     AND t2.DataKey LIKE CONCAT(t.DataKey, '_')
WHERE t2.ID is NULL
```

The join will succeed only of the current row is part of a sequence. If the row is the last `DataKey` of the sequence the join will not succeed, and I'm returning the row.

See fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3683e/1).

Comment: For what it's worth, [this more tricky dataset](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/78ec8/17) gives incorrect results. Though to be fair this trickier data is not in the original post, it's a reasonable use case scenario.

Comment: @ErikE okay, I thought you were after this (I tested my query already with that dataset), but if it's wrong, I think that now I understand your requirements better (so the first row it has to return is 6, abcd, test, right?) I'll edit my answer

Comment: @ErikE I thought you were the OP, I'm sorry :) I changed my inner query, now it should be okay

Comment: I know, I seem like I'm the OP because I put the bounty... but it was an interesting problem and I stepped in since the OP has been absent.

Comment: @ErikE now I understand, thanks :) I think as well that the question is interesting, I usually don't use SQL Server much - that's why I don't know how to use OVER clause :) but I wanted to find an answer that works both on SQL Server and on MySql, I hope it's correct now

Answer (score 0):

Option with EXISTS

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.test37 t1
WHERE EXISTS (
              SELECT *
              FROM dbo.test37 t2
              WHERE t1.[user] = t2.[user]
              GROUP BY LEFT([Key], 1), [User]
              HAVING MAX([Key]) = t1.[Key]
              )
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b2d6b/1/0)

UPDATE

```
;WITH cte AS
 (      
  SELECT t1.[Key], t1.[User], ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t1.[User], t1.[Key]) AS Id
  FROM dbo.test37 t1
  )
  SELECT c1.[Key], c1.[User]
  FROM cte c1 LEFT JOIN cte c2 ON c1.ID + 1 = c2.Id
  WHERE ISNULL(c2.[Key], '') NOT LIKE ISNULL(c1.[Key], '') + '%'
```

Comment: This fails because the user could start over and begin with the same letter. It is not correct to group by `Left([Key], 1)`. See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8367b/1) that should show 4 rows as an answer, not 3.

Answer (score 0):

So you store an entire history of inputting some data and you want to get only the final registered data. Does anyone see a problem here?

**Why don't you just store the final submitted value? Or write a javascript that will use ajax to push the value on leaving the field?**

Making a complicated and expesive query to an ill-thought database table is not a good idea. Always try to store what you will later need in the form that will be convenient to get, even if you have to spend some time to process the data or obtain the data programiatically.

Imagine having millions of rows in such table. The double-nested query will kill your database if you have to perform it often.

Comment: My query isn't "double-nested" so it is possible to do it with a single scan. I agree the design of the data is problematic, but do you have any query mojo at all to offer in addition to the (constructive (?)) criticism?

Comment: @ErikE nope, sorry; moreover, I believe that since rows from different users will be mixed and the user can start re-typing the password it is impossible to 100% reliably get the last used pair.

Comment: That's a good consideration but without the OP weighing in we'll never know.

Comment: OP = "original poster". "Weighing in" = stating an opinion. What's OT?

Comment: Lol. It's misunderstanding night at the SO corral! P.S. I updated my answer with a new, even shorter query.

Answer (score 0):

please find my partial answer: how can we know if a sequence has started from new?  It would certainly make the answer easier if sequence ID was able to be recorded.

```
select * from UserEntry 
where ID in (
  select max(ID) from UserEntry group by SeqNum
)

-- that assumes seqnum globally unique.  If only unique per person then group by SeqNum, UserName

-- Create data:
CREATE TABLE dbo.UserEntry (
  ID int,
  DataKey varchar(20),
  SeqNum int,
  UserName varchar(10)
);

INSERT dbo.UserEntry (ID, DataKey, SeqNum, UserName)
VALUES
  (1, 'a', 1 , 'test'),
  (2, 'ab', 1 , 'test'),
  (3, 'abc',  1 ,'test'),
  (4, 'abcd',  1 ,'test'),
  (5, 'e', 2 , 'test1'),
  (6, 'ef', 2 , 'test1'),
  (7, 'efg', 2 , 'test1'),
  (8, 'efgh',  2 ,'test1'),
  (9, 't',  3 ,'test1'),
  (10, 'ty', 3 , 'test1'),
  (11, 'tyu', 3 , 'test1'),
  (12, 'tyui',  3 ,'test1'),
  (13, 't',  4 ,'test1'),
  (14, 'to',  4 ,'test1'), 
  (15, 'top',  4 ,'test1');
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ce3a9/1/0)